Agreement on cash settlement of a CDS
Suppose the 5y mid-market-rate CDS price for AlphaCorp is 50bps. The below CDS are in 1mm$ notional.

InvestorA buys protection from BankA at a fixed coupon of 50bps.
InvestorA has no upfront fee.


InvestorB buys protection from BankB at a fixed coupon of 75bps. InvestorB receives an upfront fee of 10,000 \$. Under the terms of the ISDA master agreement InvestorB will post $10,000 as collateral against their liability.


InvestorC buys protection from BankC at a fixed coupon of 25bps. InvestorC pays an upfront fee of 10,000 \$. Under the terms of the ISDA master agreement InvestorC will receive $10,000 in collateral securing their asset.

One week later AlphaCorp has a default event. The final price is deemed at 35.0, so a compensation sum is payable to the tune of 650,000 \$, to each investor from each bank.
It is my understanding that this default sum will also include the PV of the trade.
So, if the CDS at default was still priced with 50bps,

the NPV of InvestorA's CDS is zero so she receives 650,000.


the NPV of InvestorB's CDS is -10,000 so she receives 640,000 (but she also received 10,000 a week ago), and collateral is returned.


the NPV of InvestorC's CDS is +10,000 so she receives 660,000 (but she also paid 10,000 a week ago), and collateral is returned.

Net net, it doesn't appear to matter what coupon the CDS was struck at - none of the Investors are advantaged or disadvantaged by any option.
But, all of this seems to hinge on the determination of the final value of the CDS, which may be difficult to value after such a default event has occurred. In particular, the Banks and Investors may disagree on the mid market NPV of the existing obligation.
Is this a roughly accurate picture of reality? Is there a standard, transparent settlement procedure for evaluating the NPV of the contract, so that all parties can agree? Am I missing anything blindingly obvious?

CDS are OTC, so the parties can agree to any custom terms they like. However this isn't quite how standardized ISDA contracts work.
The mtm of the swap before the event, and the historical upfront fee don't matter at all, water under the bridge.
Rather, after the event:
The Determinations Committee votes that an event has occurred, and on what date.
An auction is held to determine the price of the defaulted bond.
The protection buyer owes to the protection seller the periodic payment accrued until the day of the event. (This is different from bonds, whose accrued is wiped out.)
The protection seller owes to the protection buyer the notional.
The protection buyer owes to the protection seller either (physical settlement) debt that is pari passu with the reference obligation, face value = notional; or (cash settlement) the pv of this debt, established at an ISDA-run auction; or (very rare, not a standard contract!) some other contractually specified "fixed recovery", which may be 0.
The margins associated with the swap(s) are adjusted, and all the cash flows are netted.
Some useful readings:
https://www.investopedia.com/articles/bonds/09/what-happens-to-single-name-cds.asp not great Investopedia article
https://www.isda.org/traditional-protocol/big-bang-protocol/ ISDA 2009
https://www.creditfixings.com/CreditEventAuctions/static/credit_event_auction/docs/credit_event_auction_primer.pdf Markit / CreditEx credit event auction primer
https://www.richmondfed.org/-/media/richmondfedorg/publications/research/economic_quarterly/2019/q2/sultanum.pdf Paulos, Sultanum, Tobin paper with some history
https://www.cdsdeterminationscommittees.org/ Determinations Committee home page
https://www.cdsdeterminationscommittees.org/cds/rite-aid-corporation/ Example committee decision that Ride Aid had an event
https://www.creditfixings.com/CreditEventAuctions/results.jsp?ticker=RAD Example Right Aid auction results

Most of these very useful docs discuss the arbitration to derive the auction price which determines the protection payout. Fully understand that. If the prior NPV and historical cashflows are irrelevant (water under bridge as you say), wont that position one of these investors to be in a better position, i.e. InvestorB, because she was compensated (upfront in 10k) for committing to higher coupons (75bps) on a running basis. But she will no longer have to pay those due to cessation of contract and will simply receive 650k payout. InvestorC is worse off because she committed to lower coupons on

a running basis (25bps) and paid upfront (10k) to do so. But the almost immediate default left her disadvantaged by the decision. Just instinctively feels like there is something I haven't clocked.

If the credit is trading atvinvestment grade spread, and investor A buys CDS protection, and a week later a credit event occurs, then the credit was tremendously mispriced - a very unusual good luck for A, very bad luck for protection seller. It's like shorting a blue chip stock and having the company go out of business shortly after. Enron is the only example that comes to my mind. People trading CDS protection on IG names think more about spreads widening than about actual events. ...

When CDS became popular in the 1990s, the convention was to have zero mark to market at inception, no upfront fee, just like interestcrate swaps, and to pay annually the same spread that was being quoted. Among other consequences, after some time has passed and the credit spread moved in the market, there might be a disagreement between counterparty as to mark to market, i.e. the fee to unwind or reassign an existig swap. Also people used to be moenable to trade more bespoke/non-standard terms and conditions, like no running spread- all upfront- or fixed/zero recovery or custom credit event...

In contrast, today everything is standardized. If a name is quoted at 50bps, then A's only choice is to receive upfront and pay 100bps per annum. If a name is distressed enough, then A is more likely to have to pay 500bps per annum. Anything non-standard, you're unlikely to find anyone to trade with, or huge bid-ask spread. On the other hand, disagreements about mark to market / fee to unwind are much less likely now.
